# clang - cannot find -lc++experimental: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I am trying to compile the simplest .cpp file using clang++-15.

The following works:

```
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
```

But when I add the -fexperimental-library it fails:

```
clang++-15 -fexperimental-library -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++experimental: No such file or directory
```

What exactly is missing? Searching online didn't yield any results.

OS: linux Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you install clang++-15? It seems that ``c++experimental.a`` is missing from the installation. As far as I know not all packages include this. I don't know about Ubuntu in particular, though.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich The problem is that I did not install it. so I don't know how it was installed. I tried removing it and reinstalling with apt. it did not help.

Comment: You might need package ``libc++-15-dev``, if it is not installed. (According to this https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libc++-15-dev/filelist ``libc++experimental.a`` is included in this package.